# Qubes OS does not see the laptop camera

Tags: linux, camera, qubes

Qubes Devices does not see the camera, only the microphone. If I type `lsusb` the camera is visible:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 Root Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1358:c123 Realtek Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:5110 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co, Ltd. Goodix fingerprint device 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:1040 Quanta Computer, Inc. ov9734_techfront_camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 3151:3020 YICHIP wireless device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 Root Hub
```

How to configure the camera please help.

The camera is not on the list, If I type `qvm-pci`

```
BACKEND:DEVID DESCRIPTION IS USED
dom0:00_00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex                                          
dom0:00_00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU                                                       
dom0:00_01.0 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge                 
dom0:00_01.3 PCIe Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]                                  
dom0:00_01.7 PCI Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0]                                  
dom0:00_08.0 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge                 
dom0:00_08.1 PCI Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal Bridge PCIe GPP 0 to Bus A                    
dom0:00_14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller                                                     
dom0:00_14.3 ISA Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge                                                      
dom0:00_18.0 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: function 0                                 
dom0:00_18.1 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1                                 
dom0:00_18.2 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2                                 
dom0:00_18.3 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3                                 
dom0:00_18.4 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4                                 
dom0:00_18.5 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5                                 
dom0:00_18.6 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6                                 
dom0:00_18.7 Host Bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7                                 
dom0:01_00.0 Non-Volatile Memory Controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD                                    
dom0:02_00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter sys-net
dom0:03_00.0 VGA-compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso                                          
dom0:03_00.1 Audio Device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller               
dom0:03_00.2 Encryption Controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 17h Family Platform Security Processor (Model 10h-1fh)  
dom0:03_00.3 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1                                                   
dom0:03_00.4 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1                                                   
dom0:03_00.5 Multimedia Controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor           
dom0:03_00.6 Audio Device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

In the manual for the documentation you left it said so. Also when entering `qvm-usb`:

```
[ivan@dom0 ~]$ qvm-usb 
BACKEND:DEVID DESCRIPTION USED BY
[ivan@dom0 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [qubes-usb](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/how-to-use-usb-devices/) to pass the USB device to the VM. From dom0, run `qvm-usb` to list devices, as well as attach and detach them.

Comment: My camera is not on the list if I enter qvm-pci

Comment: @АлексШевцов why are you using `qvm-pci`?  Are you trying to pass through the entire USB controller?

Comment: In the manual for the documentation you left it said so. Also when entering `qvm-usb`:
`[ivan@dom0 ~]$ qvm-usb 
BACKEND:DEVID DESCRIPTION USED BY
[ivan@dom0 ~]$`

Comment: The manual also says to use qvm-pci to share a USB controller, not an individual USB device.